# What's the difference between Stream.builder() and calling stream() on an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there any difference between using `Stream.builder()` versus creating an `ArrayList` and then calling `stream()` on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an implementation detail, but yes, the builder is better optimized to the use case of being incrementally filled, followed by an operation streaming over the contained elements.

In contrast, an `ArrayList` has to support arbitrary modification and random access.

So, when repeatedly adding elements to an `ArrayList` without specifying a correctly predicted initial capacity, it may need to allocate a new, larger array and copy the current array into it whenever the current capacity is exhausted.

In contrast, the builder has a special support for the single element case, which doesn’t need an array at all. Then, if more elements are added, it will turn to a *spined buffer*. This buffer starts with a small array like `ArrayList` but when its capacity is exhausted, it begins to use an array of arrays instead of repeatedly copying the array to a larger flat array.

So this saves the copying costs you’d have when filling an `ArrayList`. You can save these costs for `ArrayList` by specifying the right initial capacity, but that only works when an estimate is available. Specifying an initial capacity also removes the optimization for the empty case. So generally, the stream builder can deal with unknown sizes much better.

Another property of this design is that `Stream.Builder` can deal with more than 2³¹ elements, unlike `ArrayList`, if you have enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.builder()` is not a terminal operation, so it's lazy. Using the second one, in theory, uses more memory. From the [`Stream.Builder` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html), *This allows the creation of a `Stream` by generating elements individually and adding them to the `Builder` (without the copying overhead that comes from using an `ArrayList` as a temporary buffer.)*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Stream builder is eager, you need to manually register items in there using add() method

Comment: Just to clear out the possible confusion - Elliott's comment became an answer so I moved the dangling comment here

Comment: There's an extra copying overhead related to ArrayList's internal array expanding, but you get rid of that by presizing it

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek But then you need to know the size ahead-of-time. Internally, the builder implementation uses a class named `java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer` (once there's more than one element). The Javadoc of that class states: "_One or more arrays are used to store elements. The use of a multiple arrays has better performance characteristics than a single array used by ArrayList, as when the capacity of the list needs to be increased no copying of elements is required.  This is usually beneficial in the case where the results will be traversed a small number of times_".

Comment: @Elliott "_Stream.builder() is not a terminal operation, so it's lazy_" – the `#builder()` method is not a stream operation at all, terminal or otherwise, so it doesn't make sense to say it's lazy. The method is a static method that simply returns a `Stream.Builder` instance.

Comment: @Slaw fair enough, SpinedBuffer wins indeed if you don't know the size ahead of time (which is rarely the case, to be honest)

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek you are over-simplifying, if you ever deal with `Spliterator`s directly, there are many cases when you do not know the size. I like the `Stream::builder` because I essential can write this: `Spliterator<Integer> sp = List.of(1, 2, 3).spliterator();
        Stream.Builder<Integer> b = Stream.builder();
        sp.tryAdvance(b);` It's very simplified, but you should get the point...